# XPath to get siblings based on base-sibling value

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to build a XPath expression to find siblings, based on data of a base-sibling.

Example XML:

```
<data>
    <meta>
        <material>123456</material>
        <type>a</type>
    </meta>
    <meta>
        <material>456789</material>
        <type>b</type>
    </meta>

    <dataobj0>
        <material>123456</material>
        <somedata>Test0</somedata>
    </dataobj0>
    <dataobj0>
        <material>456789</material>
        <somedata>Test1</somedata>
    </dataobj0>
    
    <dataobj1>
        <material>123456</material>
        <somedata>Test2</somedata>
    </dataobj1>
    <dataobj1>
        <material>456789</material>
        <somedata>Test3</somedata>
    </dataobj1>
</data>
```

I iterate over all `<meta>` elements and for each meta element, I want to find the matching dataobj0 and dataobj1. So when I am in `<meta><material>123456</material></meta>`, I want to access `/data/dataobj0[material = "123456"]` and `/data/dataobj1[material = "123456"]`

I though something like:
`../dataobj0[material = ./material]` or `following-sibling::dataobj0[material = ./material]` would work, but in this case `./material` has already the number of the sibling.

Any ideas, how I could get the materialnumber of the current meta element here?

Answer (score 0):

To get, for example, the dataobj corresponding to the second `<meta>` (the one with `<type>b</type>`), use

```
//*[starts-with(name(),"dataobj")][material=(//meta/material)[2]]/somedata
```

If you are using xpath>1.0 you can pair them like this:

```
//*[starts-with(name(),"dataobj")][material=(//meta/material)[2]]/(somedata/text() | //meta[.//material=material][2]//type/text())
```

and get this output:

```
b
Test1
Test3
```